# Dynamically creating subdomains on Heroku with nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, subdomain

Is it possible to dynamically add subdomain names to a custom domain that is pointing to your heroku app?

For example, you're creating an app that allows users to create their own pages.  Let's say `www.example.com` is pointing to your heroku app and a user named John makes a page and your app creates `john.example.com` that has johns content.

For node, can you do this through routing in express?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can indeed dynamically add domains to your Heroku app using the [Heroku Platform API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference). Here's a link to the exact bit you need: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#domain

You can then read in the domain data via the node request object (`req.url`, I believe).

Comment: How would one deal with SSL for these websites for their customers? similar to the way that Squarespace provides SSL certificates for their customers and their custom domains. Does a new SSL certificate need to be purchased for Each one?